# how to determine the sequence generated by these generating functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I'm having hard time figuring out the sequence generated by each of these generating functions.

1. $f(x) = {x^4\over (1-x)}$
2. $f(x) = {1\over (3-x)}$
3. $f(x) = {1\over (1-x)+3x^7-11}$
4. $f(x) = {1\over (1+3x)}$

for #1, since $1\over (1-x)$ is $1 + x + x^2 + x^3+ X^4...$ and so on, I have $x^4+x^8+x^12+x^16$ and so on.. but how do I get the sequence(like 0,0,1,1 and so on)?

Any help would be very much appreciated thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe, #1 is just
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{x^4}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{4+i} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i,
\end{equation*}
where $a_i = 1$ if $i\ge 4$, and $a_i = 0$ otherwise. For #2, rewrite $\frac{1}{3-x}$ as
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{3-x} = \frac{1/3}{1-(x/3)} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(x/3)}.
\end{equation*}
Then use the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ with $\frac{x}{3}$ in place of $x$.

Comment: thankyou, so for #1 is it just 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 and so on?

Comment: That's right. And for #2, if you think of the power series for $1/(1-x)$ as having $1$'s as each coefficient, then do the arithmetic I suggested, you'll be able to figure out #2 as well.

Comment: Actually, you need to be a bit careful. The first number in your list should correspond to $i=0$, right? So for #1 it should be $0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, \dots$ (four leading zeros, not three).

Comment: The first equality is not correct.  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{4i}=\frac 1{1-x^4}$, not $\frac {x^4}{1-x}$

Comment: Ack. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: thankyou, I'm wondering (since you edited bit of your answer), 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1 is still correct for #1 right? and for #2, when I replace x by x/3 I get x/3 + x/3^0 + x/3^1 + x/3^2 and so on. So does that mean ai = 1 if x is divisible by 3 and otherwise its 0. Is it correct??

Comment: No, that series is not correct for 1.  For 2, the coefficients will not be all $1$'s, they will be powers of $3$

Comment: i see for 1, then it should be 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1... and for 2, it should be 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1 right?

Answer (score 1):

For 1, you are correct that $\frac 1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots $.  You should multiply it by $x^4$, so there are terms in $x^5$ and $x^6$, etc.  rogerl has dealt with 2.  For 3 you just update the affected terms in $\frac 1{1-x}$  For 4, define $y=-3x$, write the generating function in $y$ and substitute back in for $x$

Comment: sorry about that, I just edited number 4

Comment: Updated in light of the edit.

Comment: Are you sure that you don’t want to suggest $y=-3x$ in the last one?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, that is better.